# Copying files hanged at 99%, then the flash memory disappeared. How to show it?

Tags: 18.04, usb, windows-10

I was copying some big files (around 1 GB) to a flash drive. It froze near the end. it took several minutes then the flash drive disappeared. I tried to reconnect it but it won't show up. I also connected it to a Windows 10 machine, I can hear a tick sound out of windows (meaning a USB connected) but it again won't show up. I can't format it. I can't access it. I read some topics about it but in those cases it just freezes (I understand why, it has to do something with buffering), in my case the flash drive disappeared and I couldn't find much about it on the Internet. How to bring it up again in Ubuntu and Windows?

Windows 10 version: 1903

Ubuntu: 18.04.3

Comment: Look at the last lines of dmesg | tail -33  and see if the USB is recognized as a device.  If not, it's probably fried, since Windows doesn't see it either.  Before tossing it, physically pull it apart and see if the memory inside is actually a micro-sd.  The card may be OK if it's only the USB reader electronics that overeheated. The smaller the USB, the more likely it is to overheat with large writes (less heat dissapation).